# Selenium IDE - how to test for CSS

Tags: css, selenium

I'm learning Selenium IDE (Firefox plugin)

I've managed to test where there a single class in my element, but now I have 2 and it's failing

When my element is

```
<div id="me" class="one">
```

then I can use

```
assertElementPresent
css=div[id='me'][class='one']
```

And my test passes

Now I need to test the following element

```
<div id="me" class="one two">
```

I have attempted the following, none work

```
assertElementPresent
css=div[id='me'][class='one two']
```

and

```
assertElementPresent
css=div[id='me'][class='one '][class='two]


assertElementPresent
css=div[id='me'][class='one'][class=' two]
```

What do I need to do so I can verify that the ID ('me') has the css 'one two'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`one` and `two` are two different classes, the space is not part of their names

```
assertElementPresent
css=div[id='me'][class='one'][class='two']
```

Comment: As an aside, is it possible to detect alerts using Selenium IDE (no webdriver)? `assertAlertPresent` doesn't seem to help

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions Sorry, but I don't know anything about selenium IDE. I do know what I wrote about the classes so I thought I will try to help :)